# JSON fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am not too sure why I am getting this error.  Is there something I am not checking for in terms of an optional value or some sort of option that I am missing

```
func getJSON(){

    let url = NSURL(string: myURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data,response,error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data:data!)

            let theTitle = swiftyJSON["results"].arrayValue

            for title in theTitle{

                let titles = title["title"].stringValue
                print(titles)
            }


        } else{
            print("Error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this error, which line?

Comment: Your naming (plural - multiple items `theTitle` and singular - one item `titles`) is pretty confusing. And since you are using Swift 3 there are `URL` and `URLRequest`.

Comment: The error is on the request line:    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

Comment: Then the URL is bad and forced unwrapped `url!` causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is that `url` is nil when you force unwrap it, then that implies that on the line before it, where you create `url` you've passed a value in `myURL` that can't actually be parsed into an `NSURL` object, for some reason.

Print out `myURL` and see what it is.  I bet it isn't well-formed.

As an aside, you shouldn't be force unwrapping anyway.  Try something like this:

```
guard let url = NSURL(string: myURL) else {
  print("Couldn't parse myURL = \(myURL)")
  return
}

let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)  // <-- No need to force unwrap now.
```

Comment: wow thank you so much.  So is unwrapping like a safety net of sorts?

Comment: Not exactly.  There are some cases where you need to say, "no, really, trust me, I know what I'm doing", but for the most part if you have an optional, you need to properly unwrap it before using it.  The easiest way is to use `guard let foo = someOptional` or `if let foo = someOptional`.

Comment: Much appreciated.  I am new to swift so this was very helpful

Comment: Further reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: @NickBalistreri You should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu and read the relevant sections of Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book.